# UIKit: [UIViewController mutableChildViewControllers] crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, crash, crash-reports

I recently received a crash report from itunes connect. Actually it's the only crash report I got from thousands of users, yet. It's an iPod4,1 device. Interesting parts are:

```
Date/Time:       2012-02-27 22:53:27.596 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x338958bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x303891e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   UIKit                           0x31259749 -[UIViewController mutableChildViewControllers] + 1
3   UIKit                           0x31259349 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 37
4   MyApp                           0x000081e5 -[MyListController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (MyListController.m:207)
5   UIKit                           0x312d3565 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 945
6   UIKit                           0x3134bce7 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 159
```

It seems that the crash occurs when a row from a table view is selected, and a new view controller is pushed into navigation. According to my code, the new view controller is created already, so the crash occurred in `UINavigationController`.

It doesn't look like the fault of the code I wrote. And I wonder if I'm correct on this? How do I debug this problem?

Comment: I'm exploring an identical crash (except on iOS 5.1) with no luck so far.

Comment: @Jason is it happening to iPod too? I've got another crash report relating to low memory warning also occurred only once on an iPod.

Comment: it's an iPad in my case...ever find any solution to that?

Comment: From the crash log, it looks like the problem originates from a call made on line 207 in myListViewController.m, apparently inside the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. It's most likely trying to push a view controller that's no longer in memory. Can you post the code from the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in your myListViewController class?

Comment: It's pretty clear that this method only pushed a new view controller into the navigation stack. I thought it's pretty obvious considering the crash happened during the "push".

Comment: I was curious to see the code to determine whether you're initializing the view controller when the user taps the cell, or pushing a viewController that was initialized at some point earlier and apparently is no longer around. Just trying to help...

Comment: Interesting part is: ``MyController *c = [[MyController alloc] init];`` and ``[self.navigation pushViewController:c animated:YES]``.

Comment: Since it's crashing on mutableChildViewControllers I would suspect something in the previous set of viewControllers has gone wrong, for instance you over-released one.

Comment: @Bryan, since ARC is managing it for me, and it happens on very rare occasions, I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Ok.  Is it actually throwing an exception?  If so, you could catch it and see what it says.  Better if you could get the console log for that particular crash, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Bryan, if I were able to reproduce this I wouldn't be posting a question. Judging by the upvotes, I think this mysterious crash is troubling others too. It never shows up when you are debugging, or generate low-mem warning in the simulator.

Comment: FYI I find your tone a little rude; please consider I am trying to help.  What I mean is: if you put the catch in your app and release an update, then if it ever happens again you will have the information.

Comment: @Bryan, sorry but I meant no disrespect, the comment on this post is already too long, and what you suggested doesn't help in solving the problem.

Comment: Does the crash report give the exception string, or just the backtrace?

Comment: @tc. iTunesConnect crash reports only provided this much information. Exception string cannot be seen without console access. Like Bryan said, it can only be obtained by catching the exception. However, I think it's a bad idea to catch it myself and send it over the air. I guess I originally assumed someone solved a similar problem, or can confirm this is an iOS hiccup.

Comment: The "Last Exception Backtrace" is obtained by the app catching the exception (in `GSRunLoopRunModal()` or something like that); it's slightly surprising that they don't report the exception string too. We've had good experiences with PLCrashReporter (which logs exceptions too) - there are a *lot* more crashes out there than manage to filter through iTunes Connect.

Comment: @tc. Thank you, I've bookmarked PLCrashReporter. I guess I'll be incorporating it in future releases.

Comment: Have a close look at [QuincyKith](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit/downloads) - it works perfectly well for finding such nasty buggers.

Comment: @Till, thank you. QuincyKith looks pretty impressive. I'll try it out.

Comment: @HeShiming You said it's the only crash report you have received from thousands of users. So I assume its an app you have in production? Which app is it?

Comment: @user76859403 I'm afraid this really has nothing to do with the question itself.

Comment: @HeShiming If i knew the app, you'll probably receive more crash reports like the one you mentioned above as i believe ive found a way to reproduce. Needed the apps name to confirm before i post an answer.

Comment: @user76859403, it's a bit odd but the link is http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id496228828?ls=1&mt=8 none the less.

Comment: @HeShiming good. watch your crash logs. Are they the same?

Comment: @user76859403, I'm afraid it might take a while for me to actually see the crash report. I'd like to mention that this particular crash report is received back in February on iOS 5.0.1, and I haven't received a similar one lately, on iOS 6 or 5.1.1 . I'll let you know when I see the report.

Comment: What if this the out-of-memory problem (i.e. view of viewcontroller was deallocated in reaction to didReceiveMemoryWarning)? iPod 4 has only 256Mbytes of memory, while it is retina, i.e. consume 4 times more memory for each screen than non-retina devices.

Comment: Without the code, this crash report is fairly unhelpful. Can we see the code in MyListController.m around line 207. Either the function or the whole file. You could do this easily by putting it in the question or using Pastebin or Gist.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the user got a low-memory warning. UINavigationControllers will retain their views, whereas tabbed ones will pop off the invisible ones. However, the low memory code is still getting called. Check your warning handlers prior to reaching that spot. Also, test by hitting "Simulate Memory Warning" under the hardware menu at all entry and exit points.
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=876419 shows a mess of what happens when you don't.
iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/14225-uinavigationcontrollers-and-didreceivememorywarning.html has a nice comment or so on how to handle this.

I'm betting your view controller loads something and caused the memory warning. Ensure the user can't just stack tons of items on top of each other, and make sure your app is profiled to remove as many leaks as necessary to keep the app up.

The above may not be on the mark, but should be related.

Final note, don't use ARC. Something that disallows calling superclass functions is bound to screw up. If you understand bridging Core Foundation, then perhaps ARC is fine. I personally avoid it at all costs b/c memory becomes randomly handled by Apple's under-the-hood. I've seen their stuff fail way too much

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In fact, Memory Warning simulation won't trigger this crash. My app has a very small memory footprint itself. And it uses about merely 6MB of RAM last time I profiled. I do use ARC. It's possible for certain memory to be late released. But it's unlike to hit the 24MB barrier.

Comment: Sounds like it's one of those rare cases where stuff just crashed b/c of other stuff, or the user was the small fraction who could do it. Happens, heh. I wouldn't worry about it if your Shark tool says memory is low, even a leak won't affect it until it piles on over time. Good luck with dev, and I see you're using a better log tool in the other comments, should prove handy

Answer (score -1):

I got it! I had the same problem too and in your code it looks like that a button is pressed, which causes the crash!

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x338958bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x303891e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   UIKit                           0x31259749 -[UIViewController mutableChildViewControllers] + 1
3   UIKit                           0x31259349 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 37
4   MyApp                           0x000081e5 -[MyListController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (MyListController.m:207)
5   UIKit                           0x312d3565 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 945
6   UIKit                           0x3134bce7 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 159
```

Here is my suggestion:

Two things to solve a SIGABRT:

1) SIGABRT happens due to a runtime exception that isn't caught. When this happens there is some info written to the debugger console or the device console that explains the exact reason for the exception. You haven't shown us this text. It starts "Terminating application due to ..."

Show us that text.

2) If you run your app in the debugger and set a breakpoint on the exception throw function the app will stop when the exception is thrown and this will usually be enough to figure it out.  Go to the debugger breakpoint pane and at the bottom left is a control that when clicked allows you to set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Hmm... I'm afraid you misread my question. The crash report is retrieved from iTunes connect, and it is as is. There's no console access or otherwise I'd have seen more info. And I have to say that there's no button involved, this is a listview and a cell. You mentioned you ran into a similar problem, but you didn't say exactly how you addressed the problem.

Comment: well now I have to look a it from a different way...itunes connect? Probably it's cause of a error with void...maybe..well I'm not the ass in Xcode..I'm learning..sorry if I cant help look at the dev. forum there must be a clue!

Comment: well he is right with his point #1 but I guess ITunes doesnt append the logs?... I would vote for an indexOutOfBounds :) -- Are you modifiying the viewControllers stack manually ANYWHERE in your app?